# url connection question

Tags: java, url

I'm reading a URL with the following code:

```
URL myURL = new URL("htpp://path_to_my_file");
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURL.openStream()));

    while (reader.ready()) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
    ...
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Parsing of file failed: " + myURL, e);
}
```

Could it happen, that the file is not read completely? (because of network problems or something else?). If yes, is there a way to test it or even to avoid?

The background: I'm working on an application (not written by me up to this point) and users report me that parts of files are missing sometimes. It happens sporadically so my only guess was that something sometimes fails when the file is read in but I have too few java-background to be sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere here, I found the following comment:

> ready() != has more
>
> ready() does not indicate that there is more data to be read. It only shows if a read will could block the thread. It is likely that it will return false before you read all data.
>
> To find out if there is no more data check if readLine() returns null

It sounds that the implementation with reader.ready() causes my problem. Am I wrong with this assumption?

Comment: You should not be using ready() in your while loop. ready() indicates the thread will not block, not that there is nothing left to ready. You need to use read() which will tell you how many bytes were ready, and it returns -1 when there is nothing left to read.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you'll know it's happened when you get an **IOException** as per the [Reader.readLine docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29).

So you'll want to **catch** the Exception, something like this:

```
try {
    while (reader.ready()) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
    }
}
catch(IOException e) {
 // Bah! Humbug!
 // Should really log this too. So if you're using Log4j:
    log.error("Error reading from URL " + myURL.toString(), e);
} finally {

    try { if (reader != null) reader.close(); }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: hmm, the IOException is catched and obviously there is no IOException otherwise it would cause a RuntimeException.

Comment: the only missing thing is the finally-part. but that's after the file was read in, right?

Comment: @July - that depends on what the error handling code is doing. Can you update your example to include the try{}catch{}finally{} block and your error handling code please.

Comment: You should not be using ready() in your while loop. ready() indicates the stream will not block on the read, not that there is nothing left to read. You need to use read() which will tell you how many bytes were read, which returns -1 when there is nothing left to read (the -1 is your cue that you're all done).